# Fetch count of one to many relation with 2 different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables :
**1: A**

```
id   name
1    jhon
```

**2: B**

```
id a_id name
1    1   b1
2    1   b2
3    1   b3
```

**3: C**

```
id a_id name
1    1   c1
```

here A have many B and many C

now i need a count of `number of B` and `number of C` which are associated with A.
I know here 2 different Query can help me to retrieve the  count of  B, C which are belong to A
e.g:-

```
 select count(id) from B where a_id=1;
  select count(id) from C where a_id=1;
```

I am trying with solve it with join query e.g->

```
select count(b.id) , count(c.id) from A  a
left join B b on b.a_id = a.id
left join C c on c.a_id = a.id
where a.id = 1;
```

but it give the wrong result

```
count(b.id) count(c.id)
3            3
```

this is because a have 3 B thats why i am getting wrong result for count of C
I can solve it with sub query but i don't want to solve it with sub query or 2  different queries.

guys can you please me here to solve it with one query **without using subquery** here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of `Distinct` count i have achieved it. count with Distinct will remove the duplicate counting of ids.

```
select count(Distinct b.id) , count(Distinct c.id) from A  a
left join B b on b.a_id = a.id
left join C c on c.a_id = a.id
where a.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery in order to get an aggregated version of tables `B`, `C`:

```
SELECT A.*, B.cnt_b, C.cnt_c
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT a_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt_b
   FROM B
   GROUP BY a_id
) AS B ON A.a_id = B.a_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT a_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt_c
   FROM C
   GROUP BY a_id 
) AS C ON A.a_id = C.a_id
WHERE A.a_id = 1
```

Comment: `but i don't want to solve it with sub query` ... not sure if this what the OP wants (or if what the OP is even possible)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can't see any way in solving this without any sort of subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT A.id as id,
       countB,
       countC
FROM A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT a_id AS id,
                   COUNT( a_id ) as countB
            FROM B
            GROUP BY a_id
          ) B_ids ON A.id = B_ids.id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT a_id AS id,
                   COUNT( a_id ) as countC
            FROM C
            GROUP BY a_id
          ) C_ids ON A.id = C_ids.id
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

(Explanation to follow...)

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Explanation added to question.

Comment: `GROUP ON A.id` ... seriously?

Comment: This is equivalent to what the OP already have tried. It will return `3` for `COUNT(c.a_id)`.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, Can you ask a question that is a little more helpful, please?

Comment: it will give me wrong result as i have already mentioned in description we have 3 B so it will return the 3 count for C.
`count(b.id) count(c.id)
3            3`

Comment: Have tested the code and found the same.  Am correcting now.